# La dégustation d’un mystère, cela ressemble à la primeur d’un esclandre

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Que veut dire le passage suivent ?

> ***La dégustation d’un mystère***, cela ressemble à ***la primeur d’un esclandre***, les saintes âmes ne détestent point cela.

Pourriez-vous m'expliquer la relation entre **La dégustation d’un mystère** et **la primeur d’un esclandre** ?

Source: [Les Misérables/Tome 3/Livre 3/07](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/07)

Answer (score 2):

Dans la suite du texte on peut lire.

> Il y a dans les compartiments secrets de la bigoterie quelque curiosité pour le scandale.
>
> Elle était donc en proie au vague appétit de savoir une histoire.

Ici Mlle Gillenormand tente de découvrir le secret du départ de Marius

> La dégustation d'un mystère

Et pense qu'il y a une plus grande histoire derrière, ce qui pourrait provoquer un scandale, ou une dispute.

> La primeur d’un esclandre

Comme Mlle Gillenormand est décrite comme une fille placide, c'est pour cela qu'il est écrit juste après.

> Les saintes âmes ne détestent point cela

Dans les faits il n'y a pas vraiment de lien entre *la dégustation d'un mystère* et *la primeur d'un esclandre*. Mais comme la découverte du 1er risque d'apporter le 2ème, l'auteur se permet de les comparer.

Un peu comme dans la phrase suivante

> Ton fils a encore eu un 0 en dictée ? Cela ressemble à une nouvelle dispute.

Answer (score 2):

La mère Gillenormand est une [commère](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/commere/).

- **La dégustation d’un mystère** : pourquoi Marius découche-t-il encore ? La commère prend plaisir à sonder ce mystère.
- **la primeur d’un esclandre** : le ‘mystère’ va peut-être se solder par un scandale (peut-être que Marius voit une femme en secret !) pour le plus grand plaisir de Mlle Gillenormand.
- **ne détestent point** : la litote permet de rendre compte d'un plaisir difficilement avouable.

**Saintes âmes** me paraît plus difficile à comprendre, je pense qu'il est à prendre par antiphrase (Mlle Gillenormand est présentée sous un jour antipathique, pourquoi serait-elle soudain assimilée à une sainte ?) Sa [définition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saint) porte d'ailleurs déjà la notion d'hypocrisie (comme dans l'expression ‘sainte-nitouche’) qui est peut-être suggérée dans le texte :

> Personne qui affecte hypocritement l'innocence

Si l'on paraphrase le grand Victor :

> Les commères aiment les mystères parce qu'ils annoncent peut-être des futurs scandales.

Ainsi, la relation entre **la dégustation d'un mystère** et **la primeur d'un esclandre** est une relation d'équivalence hypothétique : ‘avec un peu de chance’, les allées et venues de Marius **annoncent** un scandale à venir, et Mlle Gillenormand aura alors l'opportunité d'impressionner ses ami(e)s par la fraîcheur et la qualité de ses informations, et pourra les faire valoir d'un triomphal ‘je m'en doutais’.

Answer (score 0):

L'expression « dégustation d'un mystère » évoque la froideur intellectuelle de l'être curieux dont l'esprit se vivifie dans l'adversité à laquelle le soumet l'incompréhensible, cette adversité qu'il doit surmonter pour trouver à son environnement une justification dans sa raison, cette adversité qui peut aller jusqu'à être celle de  l'incertitude quant à la conduite d'un proche que l'on soupçonne d'être un assassin. Il y a dans le mot « dégustation » ni plus ni moins que la notion de plaisir, plaisir de l'intellect certes, mais seulement plaisir ; des émotions d'un ordre plus affectif, que l'on est presqu'en droit d'escompter dans ce contexte familial, ne sont pas évoquées, n'existent pas.
Cette première partie de la généralité émise par l'auteur n'est pas un jugement porté sur la tante Gillenormand, c'est ce qu'il conçoit comme une vérité universelle applicable du moins à une partie du genre humain. Il va plus loin dans sa catégorisation  et il se trompe en disant que l'exaltation qui accompagne une mise à l'épreuve de cet instinct de curiosité, lequel il perçoit d'ailleurs assez justement si de façon un peu grandiloquente,  est celle de l'esprit qui se nourrit de l'horreur toujours attenante au scandale (ressemble à la primeur d'un esclandre)  ; en réalité il fait de la tante Gillenormand une vulgaire commère, mais gauchement ; il aurait dû écrire « La dégustation d’un mystère de cette sorte est pour une âme telle que celle de la tante Gillenormand  la primeur d’un esclandre[…]. Il continue par des généralités intenables : sainteté signifie nécessairement plaisir malsain dans le scandale, le savoir de ce qui est juste et de ce qui ne l'est pas n'est qu'un gout pour le scandale.